# Plotting a bar chart from data in a python dictionary

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, matplotlib, jenkins

I have a dictionary in my python script that contains data I want to create a bar chart with.

I used matplotlib and was able to generate the bar chart image and save it. However that was not good enough because I want to send that bar chart out as an email and I cannot embed the bar chart image in my email's html body. I know I can use the `<img>` tag but the issue is that the email body is populated in Jenkins as part of a pre-send script and externally generated images cannot be sent out that way.

I am thinking of using D3.js to generate visualizations with the dictionary data. I need help with where and how to start and glue python and js together.

FYI, currently I am using HTML package in python to generate html using python code. This allows me to generate html tables very easily but html has not tags for bar chart etc hence the issue.

Comment: This is a pretty open-ended question. I'm assuming that you've found out how to make a bar chart with D3. Then all you need to do is insert the data into the generated HTML/JS.

Comment: Check out mpld3, I think this may do something similar to what you need? http://mpld3.github.io/index.html. Also d3py but this look less well supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a minimal example for an html format bar chart generated from a python `matplotlib` and `mpld3`, you have,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
N = 10
bar = ax.bar(range(N),np.random.normal(size=N))
mpld3.save_html(fig,'./out.html')
```

and then use `out.html` or call `mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)` to generate the code or `mpld3.fig_to_dict` to output a json-serializable dictionary representation of the figure.